# Can we return 2 inner functions from 1 outer functions?

Tags: python, closures, iterable-unpacking

I have a function **factory(takes n as variable initialized to zero)** with two inner functions **current(returns the value of n)** and **counter(which returns the value n+1)**.

```
def factory(n=0):    
    
    def counter():     
        return n+1    
    return counter
        
    def current():
        return n
    return current
        
f_current,f_counter=factory(int(input()))
```

I'm getting **TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable function object**

Comment: `return current, counter`

Comment: I have checked with that as well but getting same error. Can you please give me exact code.

Comment: Please remember to up-vote the answers that helped you..

Comment: @superbrain upvote answers to their own questions? That has always been allowed, no..?

Comment: @superbrain well, that seems just silly (of course I do believe you...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but you need to have only one return statement. Otherwise, the first return statement wins, and the second is never run. Here's an example:

```py
def factory(n=0):    
    
    def counter():     
        return n+1    
        
    def current():
        return n

    return current, counter
        
f_current, f_counter = factory(int(input()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Functions terminate as soon as they encounter the return statement. Hence, your factory function terminates when it sees `return counter`. You can change it as follows (return after defining both the functions).

```py
def factory(n=0):
    def counter():     
        return n+1
        
    def current():
        return n

    return current, counter
        
f_current,f_counter=factory(int(input()))
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if you have found it useful